# Notification code for android

Tags: php, android

I wanna create notification and alert in android.I kno my PHP is working but I'm a beginner of android programming
                {
                    //dteam_id";
                $query .= "          , s.dt_start_timeTHEN '30'";
                $query .= "           WHEN '01:00:00' THEN '1'";
                $query .= "s.c_user_id=ms.c_user_id ";
                $query .= "        AND s.c_team_id=ms.c_team_id ";
                $query .= "        AND ms.c_user_id='".$userID."' ";
                $query .= "      WHERE s.c_user_id='".$userID."' ";
                $query .= "        AND s.c_entry= 1 ";
                $query .= "        AND s.t_alert >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ";
                $query .= "        AND (DATE_ADD(CURDATE() , INTERVAL 7 DAY)) ";
                $query.= "    ORDER BY s.t_alert";
                $query .= "      LIMIT 64 ";
                $result = mysql_query($query);

```
            $totalRowsCount = mysql_num_rows($result);

            if($totalRowsCount == 0)
            { 
                sendResponse(400, 'Record Not Found'); 
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                while( $row2 = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) )
                {
                    $data = array(
                        'teamID' => ($row2["c_team_id"] == "" ) ? "" : $row2["c_team_id"],
                        'startTime' => ($row2["dt_start_time"]
```

}

Comment: You need example for notification or GCM Android?

Comment: I need android java code for notification! :)

Comment: You need to explain what you want to do. You want to run PHP on android to make queries or you want to run PHP script on some server and show notification on phone? How you want to do that. It will be push (GCM) or user will open the app on his phone and make request to server?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
String appname = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
Notification notification;
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
new Intent(context, myactivity.class), 0);

// To support 2.3 os, we use "Notification" class and 3.0+ os will use
// "NotificationCompat.Builder" class.
if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
notification = new Notification(icon, message, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, appname, message,
contentIntent);
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

} else {
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
context);
notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(appname).setWhen(0)
.setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(appname)
.setContentText(message).build();

notificationManager.notify(0 , notification);
}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is absolutely no point to using `Notification` for Gingerbread and lower. `NotificationCompat.Builder` works with all versions, just make sure you set a `contentIntent` when on Gingerbread and lower.

Comment: I need connection with database with php,and show datas as notification